# Issue Related to Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes() in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

On my website. I have added a class file in `App_Code` containing 5 public classes into one NameSpace.

I want to get all class names containing in a particular namespace.

In default.aspx.cs file i have added.

```
var q = from t in Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
                            where t.IsClass && t.Namespace == "Sample"
q.ToList().ForEach(t => Console.WriteLine(t.Name));
```

But I didn't find Sample namespace in `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()`
how do I access the `'Sample'` namespce in above code?

Thanks

Comment: Is `Sample` the entire namespace? also, are any of the types you are looking for in pages? pages in asp.net are often compiled as needed, in a different assembly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem here *might* be due to the fact that this code is being executed in a temporary assembly created from your codebehind files.

To check this:

- Try just dumping out what Namespaces and classes are available in your assembly - e.g.

`var q = from t in Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
                        where t.IsClass
                        select t;
                q.ToList().ForEach(t => Console.WriteLine(t.Namespace));`

- Try using a known assembly instead of the executing assembly - e.g. `typeof(Sample.Class1).Assembly`

---

or... just read @Darin's answer... I must learn to type faster!

Answer (score 1):

> In default.aspx.cs file i have added

That's the problem. When you have a website (in contrast to a web application), all code that you put inside `App_Code` is compiled dynamically at runtime in a separate assembly. So when you write `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()` you are basically getting the assembly that was generated for your `default.aspx` WebForm which is different than the assembly containing the code in `App_Code`. You could loop through all referenced assemblies in the project to look for types.

To get this list of assemblies you could use the [GetAssemblies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.getassemblies.aspx) method on the current application domain.

Another possibility is to use some known type that you know was contained in the `App_Code` folder in order to get its assembly:

```
var assembly = typeof(Some_Type_That_Is_Declared_In_App_Code).Assembly;
var q = 
    from t in assembly.GetTypes()
    where t.IsClass && t.Namespace == "Sample"
    select t;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply..But how can i get all the class name from Sample namespace in Default.aspx.cs file??

Comment: @ghanshyam.mirani, you could get all assemblies that are referenced in your project using `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies` and then for each assembly execute your code to look for the given type. Another possibility is to use some known type from App_Code in order to obtain its assembly.